# how to customize formastic style?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, plugins, formtastic

I use the great form builder plugin 'formastic' to build a form. It is rather ugly though. How can I set style to it? I find little information through the documentation. Note: I use the newest 1.2.3. with ruby 1.8.7 and rails 3.0.3.

Comment: You find it ugly? Thats strange because it generates really well formatted forms. Can you post your formtastic code?

Comment: I have given up and manually build a form. I remember the code is pretty like the documentation ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used the formtastic generator (rails generate formtastic:install), you have two CSS files in the public/stylesheets subdirectory, called formtastic.css and formtastic_changes.css. Look into the first one to see how formtastic sets the default styles, and then override these in formtastic_changes.css.